# May a non-EU citizen work in Luxembourg and be a German resident?

Tags: germany, non-citizens, luxembourg

I am non-EU citizen working in Luxembourg with a valid Luxembourg work permit, but I would like to move to the German boarder (Trier) and commute every day to go to work. 
My question is: is it possible to obtain a residence permit in Germany and remain working in Luxembourg ? If yes, would it be possible later to renew my work permit in Luxembourg by being a German resident, or the German residence permit would allow me to work in Luxembourg ?

Comment: Related, but probably not duplicate because Switzerland is not EU whereas Luxembourg is:  https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/15498/14680

Comment: What would be the reason for German residence permit?

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was [answered here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19169/17166).

This is called a **Grenzgänger** (Cross border commuter), for which special rules apply.

The best thing to do is to make an appointment at the [Ausländerbehörde](https://www.trier.de/rathaus-buerger-in/stadtverwaltung/aemter-dienststellen/dezernat-iii/amt-fuer-auslaender-angelegenheiten/) and ask them how the **Grenzgänger** rules would apply for you.

Since you are working in Luxembourg, the German resident permit would only be needed to reside in Germany.

Income and social taxes are based on where you work

- with special rules dealing with usage of one where earned in another

There are [organizations that assist with advice](http://www.ogbl.lu/frontaliers-allemands/wo-sie-uns-finden/allemagne/treve/) in these matters.

---

**Sources**:

- [student visa - Study in Germany, live in Luxembourg](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19169/17166)
- [Stadt Trier - Amt für Ausländer-angelegenheiten](https://www.trier.de/rathaus-buerger-in/stadtverwaltung/aemter-dienststellen/dezernat-iii/amt-fuer-auslaender-angelegenheiten/)
- [Trier | Deutsche Grenzgänger](http://www.ogbl.lu/frontaliers-allemands/wo-sie-uns-finden/allemagne/treve/)

Comment: I believe the English term is usually "cross-border commuter" or something along those lines.