# Work in one country and live in another one, as a third-country national

Tags: resident-permit, blue-card, family, relocation

I work and live in Luxembourg (non-Blue Card holder), my wife lives and works in Germany (Blue card holder). We want that she lives in Luxembourg but still remains working in Germany. She would be there a couple of days per week for working (she can also work remotely). We are starting the application for family reunification residence permit for her in Luxembourg.

Can she keep the Blue card and continue working in Germany?

Can she hold two residence permits, the family reunification issued by Luxembourg, and the Blue-card issued by Germany?

Comment: In short yes. The term you are looking for is **Grenzgänger** (Cross border commuter). A search for this term will bring a few answers on this site.

Comment: Hi, I was searching a lot and havent found specific information for the case of living in Luxembourg and working in Germany. Usually cross border commuter is not a problem for EU citizens, but as third-country national there is not information for that procedure

Comment: Opposite way around, but otherwise the same: [germany - May a non-EU citizen work in Luxembourg and be a German resident? - Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19720/17166). For Luxemburg: there is no problem since you are applying for a spouse visa, plus the information that the spouse will continue to work in Germany. For Germany: you inform them of the change of address, togeather with your spouse, but will still continue working in Germany. Everything else is as with for EU Citizens (taxes etc.).

Comment: Ok, we will try to reach the auslanderamt in Bonn (where she lives) to ask whether there is a procedure to follow for notifying the change of residence. I hope they do not refuse her to continue working